# Looking for help understanding general mathematics with second order differential equation. Solution doesn't work.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been in pursuit of general solution to a second order homogeneous ODE for a long time. My degree is in the sciences, so my mathematics is built mostly around that. Consider my an amateur mathematician I guess. Anyway, I was trying to figure out how one might solve

$$y(z)'' + f(z)y(z)' + g(z)y(z) = 0$$

I've tried many different avenues and found many cool and interesting relationships, but nothing that solves this for y(z) in terms of f(z) and g(z). This is my most recent attempt.

Start with

$$y(z) = k(z)$$

Exponentiate in a logarithm

$$y(z) = e^{ln(k(z))}$$

Integrate the derivative of ln(k(z)).  The constant on the integral must be 0 to retain the initial conditions.

$$y(z) = e^{\int \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz}$$

Multiply by $\frac{k(z)'}{k(z)}$ on  both sides

$$y(z) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} = \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} e^{\int \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz}$$

Integrate across. $a$ is some constant.

$$\int y(z) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz + a = \int \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} e^{\int \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz} dz$$

The right hand side evaluates to e^{\int \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz}, so we have$$

$$\int y(z) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz + a = e^{\int \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz}$$

But we know that $e^{\int \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz} = y(z)$ so we have

$$y(z) = \int y(z) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz + a$$

Now we'll recurse once

$$y(z) = \int \Bigl( \int y(z) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz + a  \Bigr) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz + a$$

And now we take a derivative

$$y(z)' = \Bigl( \int y(z) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz + a  \Bigr) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)}$$

And move that fraction over.

$$y(z)' \frac{k(z)}{k(z)'} = \int y(z) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} dz + a $$

And one more derivative.

$$y(z)'' \frac{k(z)}{k(z)'} + y(z)' \Bigl( 1 - \frac{k(z)''}{k(z)'^2} \Bigr) = y(z) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)}$$

Lets subtract the right hand side over now

$$y(z)'' \frac{k(z)}{k(z)'} + y(z)' \Bigl( 1 - \frac{k(z)''}{k(z)'^2} \Bigr) - y(z) \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} = 0$$

And multiply by $ \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} $ across the whole equation.

$$y(z)'' + y(z)' \Bigl( \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} - \frac{k(z)''}{k(z)'} \Bigr) + y(z) \Bigl( -\frac{k(z)'^2}{k(z)^2} \Bigr) = 0$$

If you check this with$ y(z) = k(z),$ you will find that it yields a correct solution.

$$y(z)'' + \frac{y(z)'^2}{y(z)} - y(z)'' - \frac{y(z)'^2}{y(z)} = 0$$

Just a heads up, when I say and function, I mean those functions which are differentiable and integrable.

Okay, thats neat. This seems to me like it should be pretty fool proof for any function. If you know k(z), then you automatically know y(z), because they are the same. Just set $\Bigl( \frac{k(z)'}{k(z)} - \frac{k(z)''}{k(z)'} \Bigr)$ to f(z) and $\Bigl( -\frac{k(z)'^2}{k(z)^2} \Bigr)$ to g(z). Both of those are easy enough to solve.

Here's the thing though, it doesn't work. Also, in setting to two above coefficients to f(z) and g(z) respectively, you have two equations and can solve for f(z) in terms of g(z). It comes out to be $\,2f(z) = g(z)'/g(z)\,$ if you're interested, and this doesn't hold for any of the examples I tried. I even tried going through and solving an example with constant coefficients and then reverse plugging into the equation I just explained. I wondered if maybe the coefficients would pop out and the rest would cancel, but nope. No dice. I was left with something of the form

$$\frac{1}{c_1e^{az} + c_2e^{-az}}$$

So my question is, why doesn't this work? If I have $y(z) = k(z)$ and I make any other substitution for k(z), it could always be re-substituted back with k(z) at the end. And if I try to substitute in and other function for f(z) or g(z), it will always be able to be re-substituted back in at the end also.

As far as I can tell, I haven't broken any rules. I feel very confused about this and strangely anxious. If anyone is able to shed some light on why this doesn't work, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I am confused what you mean by doesn't work. Let $k(x) = x$, then the first term in parenthesis (your "$f$") becomes $f(x) = 1/x$ and $g(x) = -1/x^2$. According to all the gymnastics, an answer is then $y = k = x$ which is indeed a solution to the equation. So what doesn't work?

Comment: @Timothy I edited latexed text to normal text for readability. Please roll back if you wanted such a style.

Comment: @Gregory There will definitely be some functions that have solutions, but not all which is the desire. The original intention rather, is to start with f(z) and g(z) and end with k(z). But lets say instead that the equation is some $y'' + (1/z^n - e^z^2)y' + ln(z)y = 0$. Could you reasonably say that $(k'/k - k''/k) = (1/z^n - e^z^2)$ and $ - k'^2/k^2 = ln(z)$ and solve for the correct solution by solving for k from that?

Comment: @Narasimham Thank you for the edit, I wasn't sure what the best approach for readability was.

Answer (score 2):

The idea to find solutions as exponentials $y=e^u$ is most prominently used in the WKB approximation, especially if one can identify a magnitude gradation of the terms. This gives the Riccati equation for $u'$
$$
u''+u'^2+fu'+g=0.
$$
In reverse, it sometimes helps to transform Riccati equations backwards this way to a second order linear equation.

There is no general symbolic solution for second order linear DE, which is a different situation from (scalar) first order linear DE. There are some classes that have symbolic solutions, most prominently the case of constant coefficients and the related Cauchy-Euler DE. For more general coefficients one can apply transformations in domain and range that allow to define normal forms for some classes of second order linear DE. These and their basis solutions get names, like Airy, Bessel, Laguerre, hypergeometric, ... One could question if these named solutions count as symbolic solutions.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I've come across a number of the kinds of equations you mentioned while working with this problem, particularly the Riccati. Admittedly, I still can't help but feel that there must be some underlying pattern between all classes of second order ODEs. I haven't stopped working on this problem, perhaps it has no solution or is an irrational function (do those even exist?). I would like to show some work in addition to what I posted above and ask for some help understanding it because I can't find any mistakes I've made. How do I go about this? Do I make a new post?